# Uploading image MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, mean

I realise there's quite a few resources online about this, but none seem to use a method I like.

Currently, I have a form with a lot of inputs that gets sent to the server when a "Submit" button is clicked. This is all sent via a json request using the normal AngularJS controller/service, and eventually handled by my ExpressJS router to store it in a MongoDB.

I want to add an input to select an image file to upload. Everything I find online seems to do it in a way that as soon as the user selects a file, its immediately copied to the server. Not what I want. Does anyone know if I can somehow upload the file when the "Submit" button is clicked? If so, where can I find information on this?

Thanks

Comment: you could use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) or anything similar.

Comment: Smillar question and solution is presented [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280058/how-to-show-uploaded-images-to-the-sever-side-once-again-in-browser-using-mean-s/33280585?noredirect=1#comment54368273_33280585)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

I chose to save the file on the filesystem but you can easily change it to store it in mongo

The router

```
router.post(‘/foo’, function (req, res, next) {
 if (!req.files){
    res.redirect(‘/foo’);
 }
 let file = req.files.file;
 let fileName = req.files.file.name;
 if(sys.isJSFile(fileName)){
    //save to filesystem or mongodb
    let filePath = path.join(‘./images’, fileName);
    // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
    file.mv(filePath, function(err) {
 if (err){
        logger.error("Could not upload file: " + err);
        res.redirect(‘/foo’);
    } else {
        res.redirect(‘/bar’);
    }
  }
});
```

The view

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action=“/foo” method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </div>
 </form>
```