# How to show uploaded images to the sever side once again in browser using MEAN stack?

Tags: angularjs, html, mongodb, express, filereader

I am using MEAN stack to write and app to upload an image, to have a preview of it, and at the same time to upload this image to server(server in Express) and savinig it in MongoDB database. On the other hand side, I need this get this image back from Mongo and Server to display in on the browser once again.
Here is my wiring:
Client-side: Using [Farid Daniel custsom directive](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) the HTML uploading button is

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
    <input type="file" ngf-select ngf-change="uploadFile($files)" accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">Upload Image</input>
</span>
```

to preview here:

```
<img id="preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/fashion/" width="150px" height="150px" class="img-circle center"></img>
```

and get uploaded to sever with this AngularJS codes:

```
    $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    if(files.length > 0){
        var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
        preview.file = files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(preview);
      console.log(files[0]);
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
      // uploading image to server
      var filename = files[0].name;
      var type = files[0].type;
      var query = {
                  filename: filename,
                  type: type
                  };
          Upload.upload(
            {
              url: '/image/' + $rootScope.candidateList[parseInt(candiateIndex)]._id,
              method: 'PUT',
              // data: data // Any data needed to be submitted along with the files
              file: files
            }).progress(function(evt){
              // console.log('progress: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                 // console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'is uploaded successfully. Response: ' + data);
            console.log("Image succesfully uploaded to server");                     
          }).error(function(error){
            console.log("Error uploading image to server");
          });         

    }
  };
```

For the server-side I have written this:

```
app.put('/image/:id', multipartyMiddleware, function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;
console.log('Server: I get a PUT request to update an image for candide');
var file = req.files.file;
console.log(file);
db.candidateList.findAndModify({
  query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
  update: {$set: {file: req.files.file}},
  new: true},
   function (err, doc) {
                res.json(doc);
}
 );});
```

So far so good!, and this is what I get in the server side from one file

```
[ { fieldName: 'file[0]',
originalFilename: '12095188_1085272848151633_8297555958524563020_o.png',
path: '/tmp/kHFe3Cm6w831_1lWQ6OEXlOE.png',
headers: 
 { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="file[0]"; filename="12095188_1085272848151633_8297555958524563020_o.png"',
   'content-type': 'image/png' },
size: 530699,
name: '12095188_1085272848151633_8297555958524563020_o.png',
type: 'image/png' } ]
```

**BUT, when I get this back on the client side to show to the user its image part fails.** here is snipet of get codes in angularJS side.

```
      $http.get('/condidateslist').success(function(data){
      $rootScope.candidateList = data;
          $rootScope.candide = $rootScope.candidateList[parseInt(candiateIndex)];
      console.log($rootScope.candide);
      var preview = document.getElementById("preview");
      preview.file = $rootScope.candide.file;
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(preview);
      reader.readAsDataURL($rootScope.candide.file); 
  }).error(function(error){
    console.log("Cant find contact information");
  });
```

With following error:

```
**TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**
```

I couldn't find a similar question here, but I know it's commont action, and solution should be easy.

Comment: I think you are misusing FileReader, when you return it to client you can just pass url to the `<img/>` tag inside `ng-src`. You could use FileReader to show preview of the image before sending to server

Comment: Could you clarify more please? I should not use file reader after I GET from server information or I should bod an url with ng-src of image? as u can see there is no url in the object of image on the server side and consequencly in the returning object

Comment: @maurycy: where is this URL? when I read some while fileReader and readAsDataURL canot I just uset there?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

The FileReader object lets web applications asynchronously read the contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer, using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

So you are wrongly using it to read files from server

#### edit

So what you need to do to display the image is to expose the `candidate` on scope that drives the view and then in view where you want to display the image

#### html

```
<image ng-src="path/to/file/directory/{{candidate.name}}" />
```

where `candidate.name` is name of the image file

Comment: Indeed, I know that. but I dont know the alternative way to show the images from the server.Yuocanme the wrong part. Could you tell me waht should use in this case instead?

Comment: @I updated the code with removing the part related to fileRead(), and in html following your instruction it will be like
        <img id="preview" ng-src="path/to/file/directory/{{candidate.file.file[0].path}}" width="150px" height="150px" class="img-circle center"></img>
There is still no image shown on the client side.

Comment: Is "path/to/file/directory/" also should be replace by other string considering the file is no on client computer but coming from server in a object.?
@maurycy

Comment: That is correct, although candidate in that case should be the response from server (your json response)

Comment: I tried 
1- ng-src="{{candidate.file.file[0].name}}
2- ng-src="{{candidate.file.file[0].originalFilename}}
3- ng-src="{{candidate.file.file[0].path}}
No success so far :(

Comment: no success till now. I doubt if the object that I send to server in the first place carries the full pixel information of the image to be shown later in the client side,

Comment: That's what I'm saying all the time, you should use the object you receive from server not the one you are sending

Comment: returning object is data -> candidateList -> candide based on the htttp.get that I wrote. So the bonding will be with "candide". right? instead of candidate. then  I tried 
1-ng-src="{{candide.file[0].name}}" 2- ng-src="{{candide.file[0].originalFilename}}" 3- ng-src="{{candide.file[0].path}}".

Comment: I am printing console.log($rootScope.candide) to see the candide object the output is:Object {_id: "562827c293bb6bb3562737fe", name: "Mostafa", overAllRate: 0, subrates: Object, file: Array[1]}

Comment: file: Array[1]
0: Object
fieldName: "file[0]"
headers: Object
name: "12095188_1085272848151633_8297555958524563020_o.png"
originalFilename: "12095188_1085272848151633_8297555958524563020_o.png"
path: "/tmp/uaZQRk_tqAOkC16BYmqM39K1.png"
size: 530699
type: "image/png"

Comment: still no sucess on the latest formula.

Comment: Did I send  right object that has whole image information to the server? I have more doubt in this part now.